# Preselected page-template in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a back-end interface in Wordpress for a customer. I want to link to "Add new (page)", and have a specific custom page-template pre-selected so they don't need to choose one from the drop down. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two options here:

1. Add an action to `admin_head` where you inject some javascript to change the default value of the page template dropdown.
2. Add an action to `save_post` ([documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post)) and have your function update the `_wp_page_template` meta value of the post being saved. Like this:

   ```
   add_action( 'save_post', 'my_default_template' );

   function my_default_template( $post_id ) {

       //verify post is not a revision
       if ( !wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) {
           update_post_meta($post_id, '_wp_page_template', 'your-page-template.php');
       }
   }
   ```

The drawback of method 2 would be that the page will have to be saved once before displaying the right template in the drop down. You will probably also have to check if the user has actually selected a custom value before setting it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Check in: wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php
There are:

```
add_meta_box('pageparentdiv', 'page' == $post_type ? __('Page Attributes') : __('Attributes'), 'page_attributes_meta_box', $post_type, 'side', 'core');
```

If you remove this metabox in any way and replace it with your own, where your callback function do modify passed param $post(sets desired template) and then call the original meatbox callback (e.g. post_thumbnail_meta_box() function) passing modified $post param.
I think that if you add your own 'add_meta_boxes' action(called few of rows bellow), you will be able to replace the original metabox in there.